# Can someone explain the components of this C statement?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to learn C programming right now but I'm a bit stumbled upon the concept of declaring an array of pointers to functions. The statement is right here:

```
int (*menu_option[10])(char *title);
```

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: I was going to point you to https://cdecl.org/, but unfortunately cdecl.org isn't clever enough for that construct (although `int (*menu_option[10])(char *);` works correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) here

- `menu_option` is an array of 10
- function pointers
- they take `char*` as an argument and return an `int`

use https://cdecl.org/ to parse C gibberish to English